# How to find the starting and ending index of matching 8 byte blocks from two byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

Take two byte arrays, each different lengths.  What's known about both arrays is there is at least one eight byte (or longer) match between the two.  There may be more than one match as long as each match is at least eight bytes long.

Is there a really fast way to find the start and end position of all matches between two byte arrays?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that there is no way to know ahead of time what the matches could be - in other words there is no way to "shortlist" the possible matches? Otherwise I suspect you are dealing with a horribly exponential problem.

Comment: Good question, Jim.  I have already "shortlisted" the matches in a sense.  I know there is at least one 8 byte match because I've extracted all of the Int64's from the list of arrays.  Think of a table of byte arrays of different lengths.  I've created a lookup table that has the Pkey and each Int64 that can be extracted from the array.  Then, it's a simple matter of searching for an Int64 in the child table to find all Pkeys that match.  Except I don't know where the matches are.  They could start anywhere, and they are variable lengths.

Comment: I think the only way is go byte by byte, grabbing the 8 byte group and search for that in the other array. The fastest would be to create the code yourself and not use any LINQ extension methods. How long are they?

Comment: I use [boyer-moore-hoorspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) to find all the occurrences of a particular byte sequence in another byte sequence. I have an implementation in c# I can share. I find it very fast. You can find all the occurrences of each shortlisted sequence in each byte array pretty quickly. I can do 250000 matches in a gig file in a second or two. In terms of complexity it's still exponential, you will have to iterate the shortlist over both arrays - I don't think you can get less than exponential...

Comment: otherwise, I suspect @andew has the only other viable solution. you could perhaps combine this with adding the sequences to hash tables and intersect them - it might trade some speed for additional memory usage.

Comment: That would be fantastic, thanks Jim.  I'll be a little more specific about what I'm doing.  Take this sentence:

"When Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End announced that he would shortly be celebrating his eleventy-first birthday with a party of special magnificence, there was much talk and excitement in Hobbiton."

If you encode this sentence by it's parts of speech - each word is assigned a value which is less than 255.  It represents a noun, verb, etc.  

If you had each word of Lord of the Rings tagged by it's POS - you can search it in some really crazy ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have short-list of byte sequences, you can use [Boyer-Moore-Horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) to find all the occurrences of `needle` in `haystack` quickly.

You will need to scan each of the two byte arrays for each needle.

Depending on the distribution of your particular data, this may work faster than hashing and intersecting every possible 8 byte sequence.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> BoyerMooreHorspoolIndexesOf(byte[] haystack, byte[] needle)
{
    if (haystack == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("haystack");

    if (needle == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("needle");

    int haystackLength = haystack.Length;
    int needleLength = needle.Length;

    if ((haystackLength == 0) || (needleLength == 0) || (needleLength > haystackLength))
        yield break;

    var misses = new int[256];

    for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        misses[i] = needleLength;

    var lastneedleByte = needleLength - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < lastneedleByte; ++i)
        misses[needle[i]] = lastneedleByte - i;

    var index = 0;
    while (index <= (haystackLength - needleLength))
    {
        for (int i = lastneedleByte; haystack[index + i] == needle[i]; --i)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                yield return index;
                break;
            }
        }

        index += misses[haystack[index + lastneedleByte]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  When I ran this using my two byte arrays (the shorter of the two being the needle, the longer being the haystack) with an 8 byte match at position 10, the routine return a single value of 0.  I didn't have a chance to debug as I have to work today, but will later this evening.

Comment: @li3 - it's been pretty thoroughly unit tested, and been in production for quite some time - you will need to share your specific test case for me to investigate further.

Comment: Sorry, Jim - your code worked perfectly.  On my machine 10 million iterations took less than .25 seconds.  I was searching a haystack with the smaller haystack instead of for the needle.  Thanks again!  (Sorry I couldn't up vote you, but I don't have the reputation yet)

Comment: And just for grins and giggles, I tried to improve on your code.  Wrapping it in a Parallel.ForEach doubled the time it took to finish.  It's hard to improve on that algorithm - next to impossible I think.

Comment: unless it's applied very carefully, you will have an issue with Parallel.ForEach due to cost of context switching, however, if you have an 8 core machine, and split the 10 million into 8 separate chunks, and run those chunks in parallel, you might get some improvement on multi-core.

Comment: I figured out how to apply multi threading.  I did have some difficulty with Parallel.ForEach, but in the end I was applying it backwards.  Instead of trying to apply multi-threading at the haystacks I applied it at the needle.  

In the test I used to validate this, my needle was 54 bytes (which makes 46 unique 8 byte words).  I searched 31,000+ byte arrays sized between 3 and 198 bytes for all 46 unique words in .6 seconds.  Data returned is Parent & Child Id, Parent and Child Offsets and lengths.  The key is to apply multi threading on the needles, not the haystacks.  Blown away, Jim!

Comment: My website is iwordsplatform dot com.  I'm not trying to plug it - however, I want to point out that all the "focused matches" are stored in database, because I didn't think live searches were possible.  That was before you posted this code.  It takes longer to tag the parts of speech in one sentence than it does to search the text of the entire King James for matches.